Get word vectors / embeddings
I'm trying to replicate a LLM response for word vectors / embeddings.
I can request ChatGPT to search with the command
Find 10 word embeddings close to word: "containment"

to which it replies with a table:

The table above lists the top 10 words similar to "containment" 
based on cosine similarity of their word embeddings.

I'm trying to get mathematica to do something similar as specified here
net=NetModel["ELMo Contextual Word Representations Trained on 1B Word Benchmark"];
elmo=NetFlatten[NetGraph[{net,ThreadingLayer[(#1+#2+#3)/3&]},
    {Map[NetPort[{1,#}]&,Information[net,"OutputPortNames"]]->2}],1];
FeatureSpacePlot[{"containment"},FeatureExtractor->elmo,LabelingFunction->Callout]

but I'm getting
Insufficient memory to evaluate the network: at least 374.56 megabytes 
are required but only 311.89 megabytes are available for TargetDevice -> CPU.

Is there any way mathematica can do this?

Well, isn't the error message pretty clear? Have you tried closing other applications or observing the RAM usage?
